# Simple AJAX form failing to submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've written a simple form & AJAX function that should post the data of the form.

Can anyone help me determine why this is failing to post?

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/onyeLp4d/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="lp-pom-form-25">
  <form method="POST">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <label>First Name <input id="your_first_name" name="your_first_name" type="text" /></label>
        <label>Last Name <input id="your_last_name" name="your_last_name" type="text" /></label>
        <label>Company Name <input id="your_company_name" name="your_company_name" type="text" /></label>
        <label>Email Address <input id="your_work_email" name="your_work_email" type="text" /></label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <label>Referrals First Name <input id="your_referrals_first_name" name="your_referrals_first_name" type="text" /></label>
        <label>Referrals Last Name <input id="your_referrals_last_name" name="your_referrals_last_name" type="text" /></label>
        <label>Referrals Company Name <input id="your_referrals_company_name" name="your_referrals_company_name" type="text" /></label>
        <label>Referrals Email Address <input id="your_referrals_email_address" name="your_referrals_email_address" type="text" /></label>
        <label>Referrals Phone Number <input id="your_referrals_phone_number" name="your_referrals_phone_number" type="text" /></label>
        <label>How did you hear about us? <input id="how_did_you_hear_about_electrics_referral_program" name="how_did_you_hear_about_electrics_referral_program" type="text" /></label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">
      Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  jQuery("form").submit(function (e) {
  
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var form = jQuery(this);
  
    var formData = {
      your_first_name: jQuery("#your_first_name").val(),
      your_last_name: jQuery("#your_last_name").val(),
      your_company_name: jQuery("#your_company_name").val(),
      your_work_email: jQuery("#your_work_email").val(),
      your_referrals_first_name: jQuery("#your_referrals_first_name").val(),
      your_referrals_last_name: jQuery("#your_referrals_last_name").val(),
      your_referrals_company_name: jQuery("#your_referrals_company_name").val(),
      your_referrals_email_address: jQuery("#your_referrals_email_address").val(),
      your_referrals_phone_Number: jQuery("#your_referrals_phone_number").val(),
      how_did_you_hear_about_electrics_referral_program: jQuery("#how_did_you_hear_about_electrics_referral_program").val()
    }
    
    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax ({
        type: form.attr('method'),
      data: formData,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        console.log("Success!");
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (data) {
        console.log("An error has occured!");
        console.log(data);
      }
    });

  });
});
```

It seems quite simple:

1. Prevent form from submitting as normal
2. Get form data (saving to variable so I can remap some of it eventually)
3. Post the form data via AJAX so that the page does not reload

I am expecting the form to submit successfully using AJAX. I have tried numerous alterations of my code but it is quite simple so I must be missing something small or silly.

Comment: Do you have any code to handle the form submission?

Comment: You haven’t said what the error message/Ajax result is.  Does your form endpoint return json?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are specifying that the URL where you will make the post request is defined in the **action** attribute of your form, but in your html code, your form tag does not have this attribute.

Comment: Even if I remove that line so the url defaults to posting to the page the form lives on it does not work. Edited above.

Comment: Remove the "dataType" attribute in the AJAX request

Comment: Tried that, still isn't successful :/